# magento duplicate block twice in page sales order view

Tags: magento

I have an installation of `magento 1.9.2.1`, I have a duplicate block rendering in some pages this is the code used in my custom theme `sales.xml`:

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order View</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info">
            <block type="sales/order_info_buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" />
        </block>
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="2" class="a-right"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml" />
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>view</name><path></path><label>Order Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>creditmemo</name><path>*/*/creditmemo</path><label>Refunds</label></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</sales_order_view>
```

If anybody has an idea about the origin of this thank you for help.

Comment: Can you identify the problem more clearly? What duplication is occurring? Is there an example of it in the presented code?

Comment: Please write long brief. Thanks